# operator does not exist: character varying = integer in sequelize node js

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, nestjs

I am trying to connect two tables with sequelize, but the primary key and foreign key have different data types,
I am getting errors when I triggered the query. it is not possible to change the schema, it will affect the whole data.
Can you provide some possible solutions to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on the same issue here is how i resolved it:
The cause of the issue is that Sequlize doing typecasting from integer to string when you create in one schema `primaryKey` as `id` and give it type of integer and in another schema you use it as `secondaryKey` with alias for instance `userId` so when you reference to connected schema from main schema you receive error `operator does not exist: character varying = integer`
Code examples (i am using Sequilze-typescript):

main schema where id is `id`

```
@Table({ tableName: 'users' })
export class User extends Model<User,> {
     @Column({
        type: DataType.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        unique: true,
        autoIncrement: true
      })

      id: number
      @HasMany(() => Post)
      posts:Post[]
}
```

secondary schema that uses User `id` as `secondaryKey`

```
@Table({ tableName: 'posts' })
export class Task extends Model<Task, TaskCreationAttributes> {
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  })
  id: number

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
    creator: User
  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: false })
  userId: number
 }
```

so here even-through we explicitly telling that our secondaryKey is number when we query `User` schema, Sequlize casts `id -> userId`, `integer -> string`

so in order to prevent the typecasting from `id ->  userId` we can change
main schema(User) to

```
@Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  })

  userId: number
```

and secondary(Post) schema to:

```
  @Column({
    type: DataType.INTEGER,
    primaryKey: true,
    unique: true,
    autoIncrement: true
  })
  postId: number

  @BelongsTo(() => User)
    creator: User
  @ForeignKey(() => User)
  @Column({ type: DataType.INTEGER, allowNull: false })
  userId: number
```

so no collision and typecasting will be done

Answer (score 0):

The only way to join them in `findAll`/`findOne` calls is to use the `on` option in the `include` option:

```js
const items = Items.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: ChildItem,
    on: {
      // assuming that childId is an integer and parentId is a string
      childId: Sequelize.cast('parentId', 'integer')
    }
  }]
})
```